# altering the size of a marker moving in a line in animated line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

In a Python/matplotlib program I am trying to alter the size of the marker in the animated plot to show the magnitude of an array with python.

In this code if the marker moves to x[i],y[i] the size of the marker should be s[i]. Which means the size of the marker at point x[i],y[i] should show the value of s[i] at that point. Any suggestion on how to animate such a plot would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
s = np.random.randint(10,20,100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scat, = ax.plot(x[0], y[0], 'o', markersize = s[0])
def update(i, x, y, scat):
    scat.set_data(x[i], y[i])
    scat.axes.axis([0, 10, -1, 1])
    return scat,
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, len(x), fargs=[x,y, scat],
                              interval=25, blit=False)
plt.show()*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `set_markersize` in `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` allows for allows for updating the marker size just like updating the data:

```
def update(i, x, y, scat):
    scat.set_data(x[i], y[i])
    scat.set_markersize(s[i])
    scat.axes.axis([0, 10, -1, 1])
    return scat,
```